# Android Layer-List Drawable with two items not properly drawn and having wrong size

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, drawable, layer-list

I created a simple layer-list drawable which I want to use as an indicator weather or not a device is online. The drawable consists of an outer ring and an inner circle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="14dp"
        android:height="14dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorLightGray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="10dp"
        android:height="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorLightGray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

In my layout xml, the drawable seems to be correct when I assign it as the source of my image view:

[image]

However if I run the code on a device, it looks like this:

[image]

Also I had to set width and height in my layout otherwise the image wouldn't show at all.

**QUESTIONS:**

- What do I have to do so I can use widht/height of wrap_content in my layout xml and configure the size in the layer-list?

Comment: I believe, it is just truncated, because the available size is smaller than 10dp. Instead of explicit size try "match_parent" for both circles and layout_margin="4" for inner circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try this layerlist drawable:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="14dp"
                android:height="14dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorLightGray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:left="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorLightGray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Now I can use wrap_content in my layout and define the actual size in the drawable :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <padding
                android:bottom="4dp"
                android:left="4dp"
                android:right="4dp"
                android:top="4dp"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorLightGray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/colorLightGray"/>
            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="10dp"/>
        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks but I went with KodyTsang solution. Can you explain why you use a transparent solid? I always thought that drawing transparent stuff on mobile should be prevented whenever possible to save some processing power

Comment: @xxtesaxx Actually outer ring also solid circle. To show it as a ring I used transparent color for padding 4dp and then gave stroke with 1dp. So for 10dp both are grey circle after the upper changes color to transparent(4dp) then stroke of that. I hope this helps.